# javascript ImageData copy or move performance

Tags: javascript, imagedata

I am writing a "waterfall" diagram for an SDR receiver which is displayed in a canvas on a web page.

The canvas has a size of w=1000 h=800 pixels. 
The top line is delivered every 50ms from a server.
The browser (using javascript) must move all lines down one line and then insert the new line at the top. This gives the look of a waterfall where all pixels are moving from top to bottom.

It is working fine, but the CPU load for the pixel moving is very high, too high for i.e. a raspberry.

What I am doing is:

```
var imagedata = context.getImageData(0,0,pixwidth,height-1);
var dataCopy = new Uint8ClampedArray(imagedata.data);
for(i=(dataCopy.length - (2*pixwidth*4)); i>= 0; i--) {
    dataCopy[i+ pixwidth*4] = dataCopy[i];
}

imagedata.data.set(dataCopy);    
// insert new top line
// ....

context.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0);
```

I also tried to directly copy the pixel data in imagedata[some index],
which gives almost the same bad performance.

In another C-Program I did the same thing with a simple memcpy operation which is very fast. But what to do in Javascript ?
There are 800.000 pixels, which are 3.200.000 bytes. How can I copy or move them with the best possible performance in Javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = `hsla(${360 * Math.random()}, 100%, 50%, 1)`;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cv.width, 10);
    ctx.drawImage(cv, 0, 10);
}

setInterval(function() { draw() }, 200)
```

```html
<canvas id="cv" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

After drawing a line, take a snapshot of the entire canvas and redraw it with an offset of 10 px on the y scale. Repeat the process and you will get an waterfall like effect.

Comment: No need for save translate restore. Just `drawImage(cv,0,10)`

Comment: thank you, iacobalin, this looks very good. But could you please explain, what makes the lines moving down ? You draw the rectangle to line 10, but why are the older lines shifted down as I can see in your snippet ?

Comment: Hi harry, the 10 represents the height of the rectangle being drawn. what moves them down is the `ctx.drawImage(cv, 0, 10)` where cv is the current image visible on the canvas, being drawn 10 pixels down on the y axis. it's like taking a picture of the current canvas, move it down 10 px, insert a new line and so on.

Comment: accepted answer ! thanks to your solution I was able to reduce the CPU load from 49% to 3.3% , an impressive improvement.